# Vertically align an element that "hangs off" a div which is horizontally aligned with its fellow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't know how to concisely describe what I'm trying to achieve in words, so here's an ASCII picture:

```
   (+1)  | Enter your phone number |
         | Enter your name         |
```

I have two `<input>`s, one for phone number and one for name. These should be horizontally aligned (in the same "column").

I also have a `<span>` (country code, another piece of data that has to be inputted along with the phone number). This should "hang off" the phone number input to the left.

I'd like to vertically center the country code so that it appears in the middle of the phone number input.

It seems that this is possible with CSS Grid. I'm wondering: *is there a solution that does not involve CSS Grid*?

Here is a snippet of what I have so far. I'm using a "size zero position: relative element with its content in a position: absolute child" technique to exclude the "country code" element from the flow, so it does not disrupt the horizontal alignment.

As you can see, it does not vertically center the country code.

```css
input {
  height: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.phone-number-input-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.name-input-container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.country-code-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.country-code {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='phone-number-input-container'>
        <span class='country-code-container'>
          <b class='country-code'>+1</b>
        </span>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Phone number"></input>
      </div>

      <div class='name-input-container '>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Name"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost good, simply use `position:absolute` on the upper container and only adjust the left value since flexbox is already centring vertically (so no need to set `top`)

```css
input {
  height: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.phone-number-input-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}

.name-input-container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.country-code-container {
  position: absolute;
  left:-2rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='phone-number-input-container'>
        <span class='country-code-container'>
          <b class='country-code'>+1</b>
        </span>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Phone number">
      </div>

      <div class='name-input-container '>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another idea is to consider negative margin like below and you no more need `position:absolute`

```css
input {
  height: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.phone-number-input-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}

.name-input-container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.country-code-container {
  margin-left:-30px;
  margin-right:30px;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='phone-number-input-container'>
        <span class='country-code-container'>
          <b class='country-code'>+1</b>
        </span>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Phone number">
      </div>

      <div class='name-input-container '>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also do a translate:

```css
input {
  height: 2rem;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.phone-number-input-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}

.name-input-container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.country-code-container {
  transform:translateX(-30px);
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='phone-number-input-container'>
        <span class='country-code-container'>
          <b class='country-code'>+1</b>
        </span>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Phone number">
      </div>

      <div class='name-input-container '>
        <input class='input' placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not flexbox? Grid might be a bit too beefy

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex
}
input {
  width:300px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="country-code">
    (+1)
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <div class="phone">
   <input type="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone numner">
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Could you transform your code to a snippet and remove codepen link?

Comment: Could you include the input height-setting rule in your answer? It looks like this answer doesn't vertically center the country code.